# The command I assigned for scroll direction in Flutter does not work

Tags: flutter, dart

```
      child: Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        _cardList(context),
        Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/horizontal.jpg'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

I created a list and added 3 images under each other. But I can't scroll down. I thought because I did Column in Column. But nothing changed when I deleted the Bottom Column.

Comment: is it on scaffold body?

Comment: I am using SingleChildScrollView as body. Below that is the code.

Comment: I think it would work , but I will post a better way

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded` for better performance, instead of using   `shrinkWrap: true`

```dart
body: Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: 3,
```

Comment: I'm getting constraintsError

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: I'm still getting same error.

Comment: Can you include snippet from scaffold ?

Comment: remove `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: You are welcome, More about [ui/widgets/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/layout)

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable `SingleChildScrollView` scroll physic like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//<-- add this
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/horizontal.jpg'),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

both list are scroll vertically you need disable one of them which is `SingleChildScrollView`.